# Intellij 13.1.2 not unpacking exploded (sub-) artifacts

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ear, artifacts, intellij-13

With Intellij < 13.1.2 we were able to locally have a exploded artifact with exploded subartifacts for development, the actual version 13.1.2 is putting out *.jar and *.war files instead of directories.

I found this workaround in their bugtracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124353
but was wondering how to achieve this for all modules, instead of having to list all of them?

Comment: Sorry, despite having 20 years dev experience, 12 in java, and 6 in Intellij, I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Can you rewrite this with more details and an actual question?

Comment: It's actually very simple: For local deployement, I build exploded artifacts not packaed as jars or wars. that was possible in intellij 13.1, but but with the last update 13.1.2 it is not anymore. I need to have the exploded artifacts in directories because: I have a postprocessing ant task that removes all WEB-INF/lib/*.jar files, because IntelliJ does not support skinny wars out of the box. this isn't possible with intellij now automatically outputting to jars.

Comment: I just added my answer. The postprocessing AntTarget was the only solution I found...

Comment: I think that you can add your maven dependencies as `provided` and they'll not be copied into the lib directory any more.

Comment: If they were provided, then this sounds reasonable. But they are all submodules of the project. That maybe a hint for bad architecture, but that's not in my hand to change :) I did not encounter this problem until I updated the version number of my artifacts .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found my workaround by adding a maven profile for intellij and enabling it:

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>intellij</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <unpackTypes>war,ejb</unpackTypes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: is there way to unpack the war, ebj without changing the pom file? I dont want to mistakenly check-in the changes.

Comment: if it is a profile which is not switched on by default it will have no effect on production.

Comment: It doesn't work when I add it to the setting.xml profile.  It works only when I add the <unpackTypes>war,ejb</unpackTypes> in the pom.xml file.  :(

Comment: Yes i think so. Haven't used that for two years now, but we switched to jrebel